# How to correctly implement didReceiveWriteRequests? iOS6 CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, ios6, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I implement iOS CoreBluetooth client & server for sending data

```
client site
[self.connectedPeripheral writeValue:mainData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

and

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic 
{
   NSString *s= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"didWriteValue characteristic.value: %@ ", s);
}
```

and server site

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
  NSData *res= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [self.peripheral updateValue:res
                        forCharacteristic:self.writeCharacteristic
                     onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
 [peripheral respondToRequest:aReq withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
}
```

however, client can't receive any data. 
Any idea?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find any answer to your problem? I have the same question :(

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's doc on CoreBluetooth, you should use:

```
- (void)respondToRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request withResult:(CBATTError)result;
```

to reply to the central.This is also a choice when you receive a reading request

Answer (score -2):

To use:

```
- (BOOL)updateValue:(NSData *)value forCharacteristic:(CBMutableCharacteristic *)characteristic onSubscribedCentrals:(NSArray *)centrals;
```

you first need to subscribe to it using

```
- (void)setNotifyValue:(BOOL)enabled forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;
```

from client side.